# Codeigniter function returning an empty query

Tags: php, sql, oracle, codeigniter

I have this function on my model, which receives a parameter so I can pre-load some information on the view page, but somehow is coming back empty:

```
function addTicket($idt)
    {
        //Db Connection
        $DB2 = $this-> load-> database('DB2', TRUE);
        if (!empty($idt)){

            $query = $DB2->query ("
                    Select TROUBLE_ID, ASSIGNED_DATE, CREATOR, PROBLEM_DESCRIPTION, RESOLUTION, RESOLVED_DATE 
                    FROM TABLE1
                    WHERE TROUBLE_ID = ".$idt." 
                    "); 

        if($query){

            return $query->result_array();
        }
        else 
            {

        echo 'No Queries to display';
            }
        }
        else {echo 'No results to display';}
    }
```

I have an Oracle DB with a ton of entries, but the query keeps coming back empty, Just in case I did an `echo 'id:'.$idt.;` to check if the ID is being passed. And yes it is.
Also Im getting this message:
**Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object**

On my view page i have this code:

```
foreach($results as $row){ }
```

And im getting this message now:
**A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Any idea why this is not working?**

Answer (score 2):

Is this CodeIgniter? If so a better way to check for results is `if($query->num_rows() > 0) { }` rather than just `if($query) { }`

Also if its CodeIgniter make sure you have `db_debug` set to `TRUE` in the config/database.php otherwise you won't get to see the database errors.

Comment: Yes, it is codeigniter 1.7.2, After I changed the db_debug to TRUE, i got this: 
`
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number:

Select TROUBLE_ID, ASSIGNED_DATE, CREATOR, PROBLEM_DESCRIPTION, RESOLUTION, RESOLVED_DATE FROM TABLE1 WHERE TROUBLE_ID = ABC000001067442`

Comment: I think stack stripped out some of that can you provide a screenshot? the error doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Oh nevermind. because your trouble_id is a string you need to put single quotes around it.

Comment: My trouble_id is a varchar2 and im receiving a string ABC00001, that makes sense, I just changed it and it worked, thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, now is not showing any errors, but is not loading any data

Comment: You need to either loop through `$query->result()` or just load up `$query->row()` if you're only expecting one result.

Comment: I just update my main question, so you can see what I have in my view, also im sending that info through the controller like this: `$id = $this->input->post($idt);
$data['results'] = $this->my_model->addTicket($idt);
$this->load->view('ticketAdd',$data);`

Comment: Thanks for the db_debug info, it saved my hours.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the query is failing

```
$this->db->_error_message();
```

should tell you why

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

Should give you much more information about the query

Update:

```
    $DB2 = $this-> load-> database('DB2', TRUE);
    if (!empty($idt)){

        $query = $DB2->query ("
```

change ^^ to vv

```
    $DB2 = $this-> load-> database('DB2', TRUE);
    if (!empty($idt)){

        $query = $this->DB2->query ("
```

Comment: wouldnt it be $this->DB2->query() ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to fix this problem when in my query condition i used single quotes before double quotes, like this:

```
Select TROUBLE_ID, ASSIGNED_DATE, CREATOR, PROBLEM_DESCRIPTION, RESOLUTION, RESOLVED_DATE 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TROUBLE_ID = '" . $idt . "'
```